# Email addresses being set to on-hold bounce due to Away responses

Tags: email, bounce

We just discovered that we have several hundred contacts whose email addresses have been set to on-hold bounce due to Away responses.  Apparently the 3 bounce maximum is also being applies to emails with Away responses.  How do we change this?  Also, is there a time maximum interval for the 3 bounces, after which old bounce history is discarded?  Thanks for any light that can be shed on this.

Comment: It may be that the away responses are being misinterpreted (we have to do a fair amount of guess work based on the content of the email). Might be worth doing a bit more investigation if so. People (myself included) can help on chat.civicrm.org if that would be helpful.

Comment: michaelmcandrew-- You were correct.  Upon looking through the response text from a bunch of those messages,  the majority of them indicated some other issue-- the most common was mailbox full.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the hold_threshold in civicrm_mailing_bounce_type table for Away to your own choice. By default it is set to 30. Not sure why your system is set to 3.

I dont think if there is any way to discard old bounces unless you delete from civicrm_mailing_event_bounce table. Probably good idea to write a script that runs on cron job to delete the entries of certain bounce type and X days old.

Cheers

Pradeep

Comment: Thanks-- I checked the table and the Away bounce limit is set to 30.  Odd that we have so many, but perhaps they have accumulated over the five years that we have been using this system.